# Google analytics API: Only a few Segment id's returning data?

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So i'm trying to get per page conversion rate i have this code that works as long as i have 
segment_id = "gaid::-1", a few other seg.id numbers work, but any number that is connected to Conversions and or transactions just returns 0.

```
    df <- google_analytics(viewId = id, 
+                          date_range = c(start,end),
+                          metrics = "pageviews",
+                          dimensions = "pagePath",
+                          segments = my_segment)
2020-01-09 13:41:21> Downloaded [17] rows from a total of [17].

>   
> 
> print(df)
```

pagePath        segment pageviews
1                                                                                                       / Non-Converters         4
2                                                                       /blue-sticks/p/BLU
Non-Converters         2
3                                                                                                   /
Non-Converters         1
4                                                              /checkout/0ef01eda153e1e31482f000a000043be

that worked but ... this wont.

```
> my_segment <- segment_ga4("Sessions with Transactions",
+                           segment_id = "gaid::-10")
> 
>   
>   df <- google_analytics(viewId = id, 
+                          date_range = c(start,end),
+                          metrics = "pageviews",
+                          dimensions = "pagePath",
+                          segments = my_segment)
2020-01-09 13:42:02> Downloaded [0] rows from a total of [].
>   
> 
> print(df)
NULL
```

Is this a problem with my code or is it the giant hand of google telling me i cant use my own data? I am not using GA360 by the way. just the free version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my View ID, i was using the wrong one.
 i Need to use the one with the bots and internal.

Thank you all for your help.